# Find, describe and sketch the domain of the function $g(x,y,z)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

Find and describe the domain of  $ g$

let$$g(x,y,z)= x^3y^2z  \sqrt{\ 10-x-y-z} $$

my approach was by considering

$$ 10-x-y-z  \geq 0 $$

but I can't seem to know how to describe it by a   $3D$ domain sketching representation, in addition I need to check my answer of the domain approach by getting intersection between the functions in

$$g(x,y,z)$$

Comment: Can you describe what you have done and where you are stuck? That way we can point you in the correct direction.

Comment: done I  have added it

Answer (score 1):

By considering the domain of the following function we get the intersection of all the functions such as 
 $$ x^3 , Df=R$$
 $$ y^2,Df=R$$ 
$$ z, Df=R$$

$$ \sqrt {\ 10-x-y-z}  $$
 $Df$ of the root :
$$ 10-x-y-z  \geq 0$$
$$x+y+z \leq 10 $$
the intersecting domain between all previous function will be $$Df ={(x,y,z) ; x+y+z \leq 10}$$

$x+y+z \leq 10 $ which is the equation of plane :

$$ ax+by+cz=d$$

for easier sketching than the known triangle intersecting the three axis one can consider
drawing the $ 3D$ function by each two planes that is $XY$ plane , $XZ$ plane ,$YZ$plane .

$ @ XY plane , z=0 $

$\therefore  x+y \leq 10$

$ y \leq 10-x$

that's a straight line

$ @XZ plane , y=0 $

$\therefore  x+z \leq 10$

$ z \leq 10-x$

that's a straight line

$ @ YZ plane , x=0 $

$\therefore  y+z \leq 10$

$ z \leq 10-y$

that's a straight line

by connecting the three points a plane is formed and $ \ hence $ by substituting points @ each 2 dimensional plane we check this point satisfies or not with the condition we get to know where the area from the line : above or below , does the domain lie 
which will be in that case the area between the triangular lines causing the 3D dimensional triangular plane.

Comment: Df is the domain of the function